# How to create an optimized sql query for multiple dropdown filtering in php?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql

Am new to php and working on a project. At the beginning there was 2 filters for which I didn't worry much in writing the sql query with 4 conditions. But now I've 8 different dropdowns and I need to write an optimized sql for filter functionality. As per conditions to be written counted, I need to write 256 conditions which is the worst idea at all.

Here the problem is, there is no mandatory filed to choose for filtering. This giving me the more problem in applying different approaches.

Is there any other alternative to achieve this issue? what would be the best idea for optimized query.

**Example Code**

```
if($_REQUEST['action']=='action_report'){
   $v1 = $_POST['v1'];
   $v2 = $_POST['v2'];

  if(!empty($v1) && !empty ($v2)){
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE v1=$v1 AND v2=$v2 AND action='action_report'";
  }elseif(!empty($v1) && empty($v2)){
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE v1=$v1 AND action='action_report'";
  }elseif(empty($v1) && !empty($v2)){
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE v2=$v2 AND action='action_report'";
  }elseif(empty($v1) && empty($v2)){
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHEREAND action='action_report'";
  }
}
```

Comment: what are the rules? all of the filters have to be in OR or AND relation? Is the whole query related to one table or more? Are there 256 fields in total or is it just the number of possible values the filed can take? Can you give us a bit more detail please?

Comment: All are AND conditions and am using VIEW for the results. So consider it as a single table. And 256 is not the no.of fields. Its no of possible conditions to write if I consider normal way of writing the code for AND conditions

Comment: can you show me an example with 2 conditions?

Comment: Hi @DavidHlavati , updated the question with sample conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code would look like this:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ';
$first = true;
foreach($_POST as $paramName => $value) {
    if ($first) {
        $sql .= "{$paramName}='{$value}'";
        $first = false;
        continue;
    }
    $sql .= " AND {$paramName}='{$value}'";
}
```

Since the $_POST is an array of the incoming variables you can go through on it with a simple foreach cycle and attach it to the SQL query string. The first possible parameter wont need an AND operator, so you have to handle it differently, that's why the `$first` variable is for.

However this code is has SQL injection vulnerabilities, so it's better to attach the parameter name and the value to the SQL string like this:

```
$sql .= ' AND ' . mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, htmlspecialchars($paramName)) . "='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, htmlspecialchars($value)) . "'";
```

You will also receive empty values, you wouldn't like to attach to the SQL query string. So the final code needs to handle that too, and after a bit of formatting it would look like this:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ';
$first = true;
foreach($_POST as $paramName => $value) {
    $protectedParamName = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, htmlspecialchars($paramName));
    $protectedValue = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, htmlspecialchars($value));

    if (empty($value)) {
        continue;
    }

    if ($first) {
        $sql .= "{$protectedParamName}='{$protectedValue}'";
        $first = false;
        continue;
    }

    $sql .= " AND {$protectedParamName}='{$protectedValue}'";
}
```

In the example the `$connection` variable is a mysqli object:

```
$connection = new mysqli(
    $dbConfig['host'],
    $dbConfig['user'],
    $dbConfig['password'],
    $dbConfig['databaseName'],
    $dbConfig['port']
);
```

The `foreach($_POST as $paramName => $value)` goes through on each $_POST array values, so if you would you don't want some fields to be used in the SQL query, then you can use blacklist filtering, where you specify if the $paramName is in the blacklist, then you wont attach it to the SQL query.

For example:

```
$blackList = [
    'action'
];
foreach($_POST as $paramName => $value) {
    if (in_array($paramName, $blackList)) {
        continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @David Hlavati , I'll definitely try this. And let you know the result here. Thanks once again :)

Comment: Hi @David Hlavati, it's working pretty fine. But it's giving the ```action``` attribute too. I've updated the code above in the question. Please consider that.

Comment: Added some example code about how to filter out the parameter with blacklisting, so that can solve the unwanted parameters issue

Comment: Yeah its working damn good. Thanks for the help, @David Hlavati . You saved me. :)